# Count Joins from Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.2

For reference, I am using Postgres 9.2.23.

I have several tables where one table (`user_group`) is related to some other tables (eg: `posts`, `group_invites`, and some more other ones). There is, also a `groups` table, but it doesn't hold any data that I need for the purposes of these queries.

Table `user_group`:
`fk_user_group_id, fk_user_id, fk_group_id, fk_invite_id user_status, ...`

Table `message`:
`pk_message_id, fk_user_id, fk_group_id, child_message_id, ...`

Table `group_prospective_user`:
`pk_prospective_user_id, fk_group_id, ...`

I want to get some statistics for each of the related tables for a list of specified group ids ***if*** the user is a member of the group.

Right now I do this with one query for each related table, eg:

```
select 
  "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" as "groupId", 
  count(case
    when (
      "public"."message"."child_message_id" is null
      and "public"."message"."pk_message_id" is not null
    ) then "public"."message"."pk_message_id"
  end) as "numDiscussions", 
  count("public"."message"."pk_message_id") as "numDiscussionPosts"
from "public"."user_group"
  left outer join "public"."message"
    on "public"."message"."fk_group_id" = "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id"
where (
  "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" in (
    1, 11, 23, 530, 1070
  )
  and "public"."user_group"."role" in (
    'ADMINISTRATOR', 'MODERATOR', 'MEMBER'
  )
  and "public"."user_group"."fk_user_id" = 17517
)
group by "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id"
```

And for invites:

```
select 
  "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" as "groupId", 
  count(case
    when "public"."prospective_user"."status" = 1 then "public"."prospective_user"."pk_prospective_user_id"
  end) as "numInviteesExternal"
from "public"."user_group"
  left outer join "public"."prospective_user"
    on "public"."prospective_user"."fk_group_id" = "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id"
where (
  "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" in (
    1, 11, 23, 530, 6176
  )
  and "public"."user_group"."role" in (
    'ADMINISTRATOR', 'MODERATOR', 'MEMBER'
  )
  and "public"."user_group"."fk_user_id" = 17517
)
group by "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id"
```

The query to count the number of group invites is very similar to the above query. Just the `count when` and `join on` change.

Each of the queries to these tables has the same related logic for checking the groups to which the current user is an active member. Is there efficient way to merge multiple similar queries like this into a single query?

I tried using multiple `LEFT JOIN`s with `select count distinct`, but that ran into performance issues on groups with both lots of messages, and lots of invites. Is there a way to easily/efficiently do this with, say, a subquery?

Comment: Quick tip: use table aliases and avoid repeating long multi-part table names.

Comment: @Parfait thanks! I am actually using JOOQ, so this is all auto-generated for me, but I will keep it in mind for future. Also, I guess it would have helped readability if I had done that here, now that I think of it.

Comment: I thought this looked like ORM with all the double quotes and multi-part identifiers. Since SQL answers may be more complex than can be written in JOOQ, consider asking a `jooq` and `java` question.

Comment: My immediate answer is just join the two as derived tables by the group columns. Hard to avoid double counting to merge aggregate questions from different data sources.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for that. This is a legacy project with a lot of out of date dependencies, so I'll add this to the list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from user @Parfait was the most scalable solution I could find. I based my queries on this tutorial: https://www.sqlteam.com/articles/using-derived-tables-to-calculate-aggregate-values.

While this isn't perfect, and results in a bunch of subqueries running, it does get me all the data at once, and with a single trip to the DB.

It ended up like this:

````
  "groups"."groupId", 
  coalesce(
    "members"."member_count", 
    0
  ) as "numActiveMembers", 
  coalesce(
    "members"."invitee_count", 
    0
  ) as "numInviteesInternal", 
  coalesce(
    "discussions"."discussions_count", 
    0
  ) as "numDiscussions", 
  coalesce(
    "discussions"."posts_count", 
    0
  ) as "numDiscussionPosts"
from (
  select "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" as "groupId"
  from "public"."user_group"
  where (
    "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" in (
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5
    )
    and "public"."user_group"."role" = 'ADMINISTRATOR'
    and "public"."user_group"."fk_user_id" = 123
  )
  group by "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id"
) as "groups"
  left outer join (
    select 
      "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id" as "members_group_id", 
      count(distinct case
        when "public"."user_group"."role" in (
          'ADMINISTRATOR', 'MODERATOR', 'MEMBER'
        ) then "public"."user_group"."pk_user_group_id"
      end) as "member_count", 
      count(distinct case
        when "public"."user_group"."role" = 'INVITEE' then "public"."user_group"."pk_user_group_id"
      end) as "invitee_count"
    from "public"."user_group"
    group by "public"."user_group"."fk_group_id"
  ) as "members"
    on "members_group_id" = "groupId"
  left outer join (
    select 
      "public"."message"."fk_group_id" as "discussions_group_id", 
      count(case
        when (
          "public"."message"."child_message_id" is null
          and "public"."message"."pk_message_id" is not null
        ) then "public"."message"."pk_message_id"
      end) as "discussions_count", 
      count("public"."message"."pk_message_id") as "posts_count"
    from "public"."message"
    group by "public"."message"."fk_group_id"
  ) as "discussions"
    on "discussions_group_id" = "groupId"```
````